# Django MultiValueDictKeyError in admin, only on update with inlines

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have seen several posts on this error in relation to < 1.6.2, however, I am running version 1.6.2 and I am seeing this, but it is ONLY happening on updates, not in inserts.

I always get a 'MultiValueDictKeyError', in this case

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /admin/rep/listcontent/1/
"u'listitem_set-0-id'"
```

I am using postgres with psycopg2.
I have verified that none of my serial is columns needs the sequence reset.
I have tried dropping the db, running `manage.py createdb` fresh, adding entry, then trying to update it, same problem.

When I run the shell (via manage.py shell), I can do this

```
from rep.models import *
listitem = ListItem.objects.get(pk=1)
listitem.save()
```

without error.  I can change properties and `save()` updates the db just fine.  But not from the admin.

Note, this is only on items with inlines.
I have read about the fixes on 1.6.2 to the admin templates, this is not the issue.